# How to write it with for-comprehension instead of nested flatMap calls?

Tags: scala, parsing

I am trying to translate examples from [this article](http://eprints.nottingham.ac.uk/237/1/monparsing.pdf) to Scala.

So I defined a monadic class `Parser` with `success` as `return` function.

```
class Parser[A](val run: String => List[(A, String)]) {
  def apply(s: String) = run(s)
  def flatMap[B](f: A => Parser[B]): Parser[B] = {
    val runB = {s: String => for((r, rest) <- run(s); rb <- f(r)(rest)) yield rb}
    new Parser(runB)
  }
}

def success[A](a:A):Parser[A] = {
  val run = {s:String => List((a, s))}
  new Parser(run)
}
```

I defined also a new parser `item` to return the 1st character of the input.

```
def item(): Parser[Char] = {
  val run = {s: String => if (s.isEmpty) Nil else List((s.head, s.tail))}
  new Parser(run)
}
```

Now I am defining a new parser `item12: Parser[(Char, Char)]` to return a pair of 1st and 2nd characters

```
 def item12():Parser[(Char, Char)] = 
   item().flatMap(a => (item().flatMap(b => success(a, b))))
```

I would like to write it with *for-comprehension* instead of nested `flatMap` calls. I understand that I need to define a `map` method for the `Parser`. How would you do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand that I need to define a map method for the Parser. How would you do that ?

```
def map[B](f: A => B): Parser[B] = {
  val runB = {s: String => ???} // you need to call run and f here
  new Parser(runB)
}
```

I am leaving the body of `runB` in case you want to do it yourself.

Comment: Thank. Could you show how `item12` can be implemented with _for-comprehension_ ?

Comment: `for(a <- item(); b <- item()) yield success(a, b)`

Comment: @GabrielePetronella No, it does not compile. It probably should be `for(a <- item(); b <- item()) yield (a, b)`

Comment: @Michael, oh right you want to return a tuple. But then where's the success call?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella If you define `map`  it is not necessary. On the other hand we can say that `map(f: A = B) = flatMap(a => success(f(a)))`, so `success` is in the `map` :))